# How does one actually use a has_many/belongs_to relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

My two models are `User has_many :books` and `Book belongs_to :user`.

The `users` table has only the column `name`, while the `books` table has `users_id` and `title`.

Is this how I'm actually supposed to use them? With the users table populated, how do I go about adding a book with a specific user, done by searching their name and not the ID column? I know this is a simple thing, but I really cannot find it on Google, or by re-reading my books and re-watching my Lynda videos; I know the information must be in there somewhere but it is completely frying my brain right now, and I'm extremely confused. I'm very used to SQL and learning to use ActiveRecord instead feels like trying to write with my left hand.

What I want to do is the equivalent of, in SQL, `INSERT INTO books (title, users_id) VALUES ("Wolves of the Calla", (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = 'Sarah'));`.

Comment: Just a note that the column in your `books` table should be `user_id` singular. Not plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can all be found in the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Its worth a read, if you haven't done so already.

In regards to this question:

> ...how do I go about adding a book with a specific user...

There are a number of ways you can do it, but the key thing to remember is that the `has_many` and `belongs_to` methods "create" association methods for you. In this way you can retrieve, and add to an object's associations; Rails will take care of handling the foreign keys and such, so long as they are named in accordance with its naming convention (which it seems you have done)

So as a simple example, to add a book to a user's collection of books, would be something like this:

```
@user = User.where(name: "Sarah").first
@user.books.create(title: "Wolves of the Calla")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this really helps. It makes a lot of sense, too, I just didn't see it. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Find the user with the given name and then use the association to create a book with the found user_id

```
user = User.where(:name => "Sarah").first
user.books.create(:title => "Wolves of the Calla")
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [Association Basics Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), you'd need something like this:

```
createdBook = @user.books.create(title: "Wolves of the Calla")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Rails 4 syntax
#Approach 1
@user = User.find_by(name: 'Sarah')
@book = @user.books.create(title: 'Wolves of the Calla')

#Alternatively
@user = User.find_by(name: 'Sarah')
@user.books << Book.create(title: 'Wolves of the Calla')

#Alternatively
@user = User.find_by(name: 'Sarah')
@book = Book.create(title: 'Wolves of the Calla')
@user.book_ids += [@book.id]
```